# "Duplicate Invoice id" of paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I use paypal in sandbox mode and often receive error "Duplicate Invoice id", although invoice ID is unique for each transaction, I see it in log files:

1. Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request., Response: {"name":"DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","message":"Duplicate Invoice id","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","debug_id":"bce3a245b08ae"}, StatusCode: BadRequest, WebExceptionStatus: ProtocolError, InvoiceID: #163403
2. Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request., Response: {"name":"DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","message":"Duplicate Invoice id","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","debug_id":"102d2b994e747"}, StatusCode: BadRequest, WebExceptionStatus: ProtocolError, InvoiceID: #573012
3. Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request., Response: {"name":"DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","message":"Duplicate Invoice id","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION","debug_id":"7ae230278b686"}, StatusCode: BadRequest, WebExceptionStatus: ProtocolError, InvoiceID: #330166

All these transactions are consecutive.

I have switched off this option here: https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-pref

(I have set option  "No, allow multiple payments per invoice ID")

I even created the new test user, with new test credit card and the same error

Why is it necessary for sandbox mode and how to switch off it?

Comment: You're giving the production URL of Paypal, are you sure you turned off the option in sandbox.paypal?

Comment: @DavidNguyen Not sure, can't find it in sandbox paypal, could you help me?

Comment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/merchant

Comment: I was getting this error even though I was using a unique invoice_number for each transaction request. That setting solved the problem, but I don't understand why it is reporting a duplicate when it is not possible.